# How to find rest mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity, mass-energy

I have two identical massess with rest mass $m_0$. One of them is made to move with very high velocity $v$, while other is at rest. At some point in time the moving mass collides with the stationary mass and gets stuck to it, now they both move as 1 body with some unknown velocity.
My Doubt-
I want to know the rest mass of this new body formed by collision of the old 2 massess.
I am seriously surprised to find out that it is not $2m_0$.
Please explain what's happening here and why $2m_0$ is not the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

In relativity, mass is the length of a vector. Specifically, it is $$m^2 c^2=E^2/c^2-p^2=-P_\mu P^\mu$$ where $P^\mu=(E/c,\vec p)$ is the four-momentum vector.

Because mass is the length of a vector, it is not additive. This is exactly the same as other lengths of vectors, like speed. If you have two velocity vectors $$\vec v=(3,0,0)$$$$\vec u=(0,4,0)$$ then the speeds are $v=3$ and $u=4$. When you add $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ the resulting speed is $5$, not $7$. To find it you have to add $\vec u+\vec v$ first, and then take the magnitude second to get the combined speed.

Since mass is the magnitude of the four-momentum vector, the same rule applies. You have to add the four-momenta first and take the magnitude second. So for the mass at rest $P^\mu=(m_0 c,0,0,0)$ and for the moving mass $Q^\mu=(\gamma m_0 c, \gamma m_0 v, 0,0 )$. So to get the total mass we first add the momenta $R^\mu=P^\mu+Q^\mu$ and then take the magnitude $$m^2 c^2 = -R^\mu R_\mu = 2\ (1+\gamma)\ m_0{}^2 c^2$$

Comment: Nice answer Dale. I was wondering, so I know 4-momentum is a conserved quantity. Is this how you found the equation with $R^\mu = P^\mu +Q^\mu$?

Comment: @JohnA. no, that additivity is just a property of vectors. It applies to vectors regardless of whether they are conserved or not. If you have some physical quantity that doesn’t add, then you would not represent it by a vector

Comment: So you are saying that nowhere in your answer you used that energy and momentum are conserved?

Comment: @JohnA. that is correct. Energy and momentum are conserved, but I did not use that fact anywhere in the answer. For example, you could add a pair of four-force to get a net force. If you were interested in the magnitude of the net force you would use the same math as here. Regardless of the fact that force is not conserved. All that is needed is for them to be colocated vectors

Comment: I guess how do you know that the specific 4-vector of the resulting particle after the collision is equal to the sum of the 4-vectors of the incoming particles without using conservation. I agree vectors add like vectors but it seems to me you need to consider these conservation laws (and assume elasticity of collision) to add these and claim they result in the momentum 4-vector of the resulting particle

Comment: @Dale I definitely understood the mathematical point of solving this question as you described, but how can you explain that with physics? What exactly happens that leds the final rest mass to become greater than the sum of initial rest masses. From where did this extra rest mass energy come?

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/795139/is-4-momentum-conservation-used-in-this-answer

Comment: @JohnA. asked “ how do you know that the specific 4-vector of the resulting particle after the collision is equal to the sum of the 4-vectors of the incoming particles without using conservation” indeed, that requires conservation. But this question was about why mass is not additive.

Comment: @AmitRai physically the energy of a system is the sum of the energies of all the parts of the system (including fields). The momentum of a system is the sum of the momenta of all the parts of the system (including fields). That is the physics. From that to the mass is just math. There is no extra energy. The rest mass energy is just a part of the total energy, and the rest mass energy is simply a bigger part of the total energy after the collision.